# JSON Request Body is escaped with KTOR

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I'm creating a POST request with a simple JSON body. When I create a JSON string like this:

```
Json.encodeToString(NewAlias(my_id= "j-mueller", alias_name= "finny"))
```

and print it out, it looks like this:

```
{"my_id":"j-mueller","alias_name":"finny"}
```

Then, when I try to post it to my endpoint using KTOR like this:

```
val response = httpClient.post<String>("https://myurl/als/create") {
                        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                        body = Json.encodeToString(NewAlias(my_id= "j-mueller", alias_name= "finny"))

                    }
```

In the logs I see that Ktor seems to escape the content and it looks like this:

```
"{\"my_id\":\"j-mueller\",\"alias_name\":\"finny\"}"
```

And I get a "400 - Bad Request" as response. Do I have influence on this behavior? Or is it just the ktor-logger that adds the ""? When I try the post via postman without the "/" in the body, it works, so I assume that this is the problem...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the [JsonFeature](https://ktor.io/docs/json.html) and let Ktor serialize a body:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
    }
}

val response = client.post<String>("http://httpbin.org/post") {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    body = NewAlias(my_id= "j-mueller", alias_name= "funny") // Do not serialize explicitly here
}
```

Or serialize a request body explicitly but don't use [JsonFeature](https://ktor.io/docs/json.html):

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO)

val response = client.post<String>("http://httpbin.org/post") {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    body = Json.encodeToString(NewAlias(my_id= "j-mueller", alias_name= "finny"))
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you Aleksei, I have the JsonFeature enabled, so ktor created a json-string out of a json-string... :D Thanks for pointing me to the right driection...problem solved.