# ktor post always returning errors

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I've been trying to connect to a web API in my kotlin android application. I'm using the ktor framework to do this (2.0.1). For now, get requests appear to be working as expected, but post requests not so much. I keep getting 400 and 500 errors back and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it has something to do with how I set the body data.

This is how I initialize the client

```
                client = HttpClient(Android) {
                    install(Logging) {
                        level = LogLevel.ALL
                    }
                    install(ContentNegotiation) {
                        json()
                    }
                    install(HttpTimeout) {
                        requestTimeoutMillis = 15000L
                        connectTimeoutMillis = 15000L
                        socketTimeoutMillis = 15000L
                    }
                    defaultRequest {
                        url("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
                        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                        accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
                    }
                }
```

And this is how I send to post request (or at least, one of the ways)

```
        val sampleRequest: HttpResponse = client.request {
            method = HttpMethod.Post
            setBody("{\"title\": \"test product\", \"price\": \"13.5\", \"description\": \"lorem ipsum set\", \"image\": \"https://i.pravatar.cc\", \"category\": \"electronic\"}")
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. If anyone has a sample I can look at, that would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have the same problem that is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530654/json-request-body-is-escaped-with-ktor except that in Ktor 2.0.* the `JsonFeature` is replaced with the `ContentNegotiation` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @AlekseiTirman. I found my answer. The body json string was being jsonified twice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.